# How to pass one django template with a 'for loop' into another one using 'include' statement?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I am working on FAQs page where questions and answers are passed to a template sections based on their categories. I would like to reduce amount of html and use section div as a template

```
<div id="{{id}}">
    <div class="h2">{{category}}</div>
    {% for q in faqs %}
        {% if q.category == '{{category}}' %}
        <ul class="collapsible">
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">{{q.question}}></div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span>{{q.answer}}</span></div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My main html contains following code:

```
{% with id='m_faq'%}
{% with category='Methodology'%}
   {% include 'main/faqs_section.html' %}
{% endwith %}{% endwith %}
```

I am only able to pass variables id and category.
Is there a way to the for loop as well?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. What do you mean by for loop as well and on which section?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to create a list for categories in views.py

```
cat = [ 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3','Category4']
```

pass it to context dictionary and then put additional 'for loop' around section div.

```
{% for c in cat %}
<div id="">
    <div class="h4">{{c}}</div>
    {% for q in faqs %}
    {% if c == q.category %}
    <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header">{{q.question}}</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>{{q.answer}}</span></div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

That will generate a template with list of faqs divided in to sections..